# Delta symbol meaning in mean curvature equation for level set

Tags: notation

In [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214446559), the equality

$$
|Du| \text{div}\left( \frac{Du}{|Du|}\right) = \left( \delta_{ij} - \frac{u_{x_i}u_{x_j}}{|Du|^2} \right) u_{x_ix_j}
$$

is asserted without explanation for $u: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Further, the notation, $\delta_{ij}$, is left undefined. The LHS is a scalar, while the RHS seems to imply components of $n \times n$ matrix (unless summation is implied?).

Is the notation on the RHS standard? Once the notation is established on the RHS, does equality to the LHS easily follow? If not, is there a reference for the equality?

Comment: Usually $\delta_{ij}$ denotes the Kronecker-Delta.

Comment: Yes, but if that is the case here, how does it reconcile with the left-hand-side of the equation (which does not explicitly depend on $i$ or $j$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use
$$ Du=(u_{x_1}, \cdots, u_{x_n}), |Du|=\sqrt{u_{x_1}^2 \cdots+u_{x_n}^2},\text{Div}(v_1,\cdots,v_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_i}$$

Comment: So, to follow up, summation is implied on the RHS, and I was simply too lazy to check :)